# why does google play store stability report say that my app crashed on one device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, google-play-console

when I uploaded my app bundle on the play store it gave me this stability report. It said that It crashed on 1 device with this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aewt
```

Can someone tell me what that means?

I'm using unity for android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried googling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by excluding the Nokia 1 from the supported devices list.